# Probability of $(a+b\omega+c\omega^{2})(a+b\omega^{2}+c\omega)=1$

Tags: probability, complex-numbers

> A fair die is thrown three times. If $a$, $b$, $c$ are the numbers obtained on the die, then what is the probability that $$(a+b\omega+c\omega^{2})(a+b\omega^{2}+c\omega)=1$$
>   (where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity)

**My attempt:**

On simplification, $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}=1+(ab+bc+ca)$. I can't figure how to find the number of cases where the condition is satisfied.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you are asking. Can you try to reformulate your question?

Comment: I also don't get how probability and complex numbers enter in this together. Maybe the users who upvoted it can edit it to make that more clear?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff $w = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$, so there's where the complex numbers enter. OP has correctly simplified the expression to get rid of them, so I guess what remains is to decide the solutions to the obtained equation for $1 \leq a, b, c \leq n$.

Comment: @Daniel R: Which means that this is not a "complex probability" (assuming one could define such a thing.) And what is supposed to come after the unfinished sentence "[...] is equal to"? The formula for $w$?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I would guess that the only thing missing there is a question mark, or perhaps "...?".

Comment: I think the problem is simply asking for the "probability" of $a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca)$, by which it means the mean of the expression, since those are random variables.

Comment: To OP and @RespawnedFluff I edited the question to hopefully make it more accessible. I think that the question boils down to proving that $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac-1=0$ doesn't have any solutions over the integers, which would mean that the answer to the question is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ and $\omega$ is the complex cube root of unity, we can write
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)(a+c\omega+b\omega^2)(a+b+c)$$
$$(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)(a+c\omega+b\omega^2)=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}{a+b+c}$$
Now, we only have to find out how many integer solutions are there for $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=a+b+c\forall 1\leq a,b,c\leq 6$.
On further simplification, 
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)(a+b+c)=(a+b+c)$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=1$$
The total positive integer solutions less than $6$ to the above equation by the total possible dice rolls ($6^3$) will be your required probability.