# probability that $(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)\cdot (a+b\omega^2+c\omega) = 1$

Tags: probability

> If $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity with $0<\arg(\omega)<2\pi. $ A fair die is thrown three times
>
> If $a,b,c$ are the numbers obtained on the dice , Then probability that
>
> $(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)\cdot (a+b\omega^2+c\omega) = 1$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ Given $a,b,c\in  \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},$ Then Total number of ways $n(S) = 6^3$

Now for favourable cases $n(A)$

$(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)\cdot (a+b\omega^2+c\omega) = =a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca = 1$

$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 = 2$

Could some help me how to solve it , Thanks

Comment: [An exact duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1137505/11619). I am somewhat inclined to close the earlier one as a dupe of this, because here both the asker and the answerer make more explicit progress, so it is more useful of future readers to see this thread. What do you folks think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the probability of 
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 = 2, \qquad \text{ when }a,b,c \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$
For the sum of the three squares to be $2$, the only way it can happen is when two of them are $1$ and the third is a $0$. For example, $a=b$, then $c=a \pm 1$. So you are looking for triples of the form $(a,a,a+1)$ or $(a,a,a-1)$ and their cyclic permutations.

For each $a \in \{2,3,4,5\}$, the number of such triplets (including their cyclic permutations) is $24$, then for $a=1$ we can only have $(a,a,a+1)$ and its permutations, likewise for $a=6$ we can only have $(a,a,a-1)$ and its permutations. Therefore

Thus the probability is $\frac{24+3+3}{6^3}=\frac{30}{6^3}$.

Comment: Can't $c = a-1$ too?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson you are absolutely right. Thanks I have fixed the error.